# How does it work: Found one SSL certificate two different chains and two different root CAs

Tags: ssl, openssl, ssl-certificate, x509certificate, x509

I bought an SSL Certificate from GeoTrust.

On checking the certificate chain on different Devices I found **two different chains**. Both chain are **valid!**

On chain ends in Root-CA  **C=US, O=Equifax, OU=Equifax Secure Certificate Authority** and the other one in Root-CA **C=US, O=GeoTrust Inc., CN=GeoTrust Global CA**.

The different between this chains are in the first chain "GeoTrust Global CA" is signed by "Equifax Secure Certificate Authority" and in at the second "GeoTrust Global CA" is self-signed. But in both chain the Fingerprint of "GeoTrust Global CA" is "C0:7A:98:68:8D:89:FB:AB:05:64:0C:11:7D:AA:7D:65:B8:CA:CC:4E", only the Serial Number is different.

How is this possible? I thought ssl certificates, the fingerprints of them and the cahins are unique!

---

Chain 1)

1a) **C=US, O=GeoTrust Inc., OU=Domain Validated SSL, CN=GeoTrust DV SSL CA** sign by **C=US, O=GeoTrust Inc., CN=GeoTrust Global CA**

```
Data:
    Version: 3 (0x2)
    Serial Number: 145106 (0x236d2)
    Signature Algorithm: sha1WithRSAEncryption
    Issuer: C=US, O=GeoTrust Inc., CN=GeoTrust Global CA
    Validity
        Not Before: Feb 26 21:32:31 2010 GMT
        Not After : Feb 25 21:32:31 2020 GMT
    Subject: C=US, O=GeoTrust Inc., OU=Domain Validated SSL, CN=GeoTrust DV SSL CA
    X509v3 extensions:
        X509v3 Key Usage: critical
            Certificate Sign, CRL Sign
        X509v3 Subject Key Identifier:
            8C:F4:D9:93:0A:47:BC:00:A0:4A:CE:4B:75:6E:A0:B6:B0:B2:7E:FC
        X509v3 Authority Key Identifier:
            keyid:C0:7A:98:68:8D:89:FB:AB:05:64:0C:11:7D:AA:7D:65:B8:CA:CC:4E
```

1b) **C=US, O=GeoTrust Inc., CN=GeoTrust Global CA** sign by **C=US, O=Equifax, OU=Equifax Secure Certificate Authority**

```
Data:
    Version: 3 (0x2)
    Serial Number: 1227750 (0x12bbe6)
    Signature Algorithm: sha1WithRSAEncryption
    Issuer: C=US, O=Equifax, OU=Equifax Secure Certificate Authority
    Validity
        Not Before: May 21 04:00:00 2002 GMT
        Not After : Aug 21 04:00:00 2018 GMT
    Subject: C=US, O=GeoTrust Inc., CN=GeoTrust Global CA
    X509v3 extensions:
        X509v3 Authority Key Identifier:
            keyid:48:E6:68:F9:2B:D2:B2:95:D7:47:D8:23:20:10:4F:33:98:90:9F:D4

        X509v3 Subject Key Identifier:
            C0:7A:98:68:8D:89:FB:AB:05:64:0C:11:7D:AA:7D:65:B8:CA:CC:4E
        X509v3 Basic Constraints: critical
            CA:TRUE
```

1c) Root-CA  **C=US, O=Equifax, OU=Equifax Secure Certificate Authority**

```
Data:
    Version: 3 (0x2)
    Serial Number: 903804111 (0x35def4cf)
    Signature Algorithm: sha1WithRSAEncryption
    Issuer: C=US, O=Equifax, OU=Equifax Secure Certificate Authority
    Validity
        Not Before: Aug 22 16:41:51 1998 GMT
        Not After : Aug 22 16:41:51 2018 GMT
    Subject: C=US, O=Equifax, OU=Equifax Secure Certificate Authority
    X509v3 extensions:
        X509v3 Private Key Usage Period:
            Not After: Aug 22 16:41:51 2018 GMT
        X509v3 Key Usage:
            Certificate Sign, CRL Sign
        X509v3 Authority Key Identifier:
            keyid:48:E6:68:F9:2B:D2:B2:95:D7:47:D8:23:20:10:4F:33:98:90:9F:D4

        X509v3 Subject Key Identifier:
            48:E6:68:F9:2B:D2:B2:95:D7:47:D8:23:20:10:4F:33:98:90:9F:D4
```

---

Chain 2)

2a) **C=US, O=GeoTrust Inc., OU=Domain Validated SSL, CN=GeoTrust DV SSL CA** sign by **C=US, O=GeoTrust Inc., CN=GeoTrust Global CA**

```
Data:
    Version: 3 (0x2)
    Serial Number: 145106 (0x236d2)
    Signature Algorithm: sha1WithRSAEncryption
    Issuer: C=US, O=GeoTrust Inc., CN=GeoTrust Global CA
    Validity
        Not Before: Feb 26 21:32:31 2010 GMT
        Not After : Feb 25 21:32:31 2020 GMT
    Subject: C=US, O=GeoTrust Inc., OU=Domain Validated SSL, CN=GeoTrust DV SSL CA
    X509v3 extensions:
        X509v3 Key Usage: critical
            Certificate Sign, CRL Sign
        X509v3 Subject Key Identifier:
            8C:F4:D9:93:0A:47:BC:00:A0:4A:CE:4B:75:6E:A0:B6:B0:B2:7E:FC
        X509v3 Authority Key Identifier:
            keyid:C0:7A:98:68:8D:89:FB:AB:05:64:0C:11:7D:AA:7D:65:B8:CA:CC:4E
```

2b)  Root-CA  **C=US, O=GeoTrust Inc., CN=GeoTrust Global CA**

```
Data:
    Version: 3 (0x2)
    Serial Number: 144470 (0x23456)
    Signature Algorithm: sha1WithRSAEncryption
    Issuer: C=US, O=GeoTrust Inc., CN=GeoTrust Global CA
    Validity
        Not Before: May 21 04:00:00 2002 GMT
        Not After : May 21 04:00:00 2022 GMT
    Subject: C=US, O=GeoTrust Inc., CN=GeoTrust Global CA
    X509v3 extensions:
        X509v3 Basic Constraints: critical
            CA:TRUE
        X509v3 Subject Key Identifier:
            C0:7A:98:68:8D:89:FB:AB:05:64:0C:11:7D:AA:7D:65:B8:CA:CC:4E
        X509v3 Authority Key Identifier:
            keyid:C0:7A:98:68:8D:89:FB:AB:05:64:0C:11:7D:AA:7D:65:B8:CA:CC:4E
```

Comment: Which are the two certificates that you think are identical?

Comment: **Subject and fingerprint of 1b and 2b!** But the issuer are different. How it is possible that 1b and 2b have the same Fingerprint "C0:7A:98:68:8D:89:FB:AB:05:64:0C:11:7D:AA:7D:65:B8:CA:CC:4E"? I thought the fingerprint includes the issuer Information. In this case the fingerprints must be different.

Comment: The serial numbers are different.

Answer (score 4):

1b is a "cross certificate"; a root certificate for Geotrust issued by Equifax.  2b is the same key, but a self-signed root.

Cross certificates are typically used to make a root certificate trusted before it as been accepted into the Mozilla/Microsoft/etc root programs.  When the root has been accepted by those programs, it can be used as a normal self-signed certificate.

Comment: But how it is possible that 1b and 2b have the same Fingerprint "C0:7A:98:68:8D:89:FB:AB:05:64:0C:11:7D:AA:7D:65:B8:CA:CC:4E"? I thought the fingerprint includes the issuer Information. In this case the fingerprints must be different. That is my problem. Or is the issuer NOT included in the fingerprint hash?

Comment: @user1407485, the identifiers you're talking are the subject/authority key identifiers: only the public key is used, not the certificate. ([This may be of interest](http://security.stackexchange.com/a/14345/2435).)

Comment: Basic-Question: "X509v2 Subject Key Identifier" is not the same like "fingerprint"?

Comment: Oh... :-O The fingerprints are different!  Fingerprint from 1b: SHA1 Fingerprint=73:59:75:5C:6D:F9:A0:AB:C3:06:0B:CE:36:95:64:C8:EC:45:42:A3  --  Fingerprint from 2b: SHA1 Fingerprint=DE:28:F4:A4:FF:E5:B9:2F:A3:C5:03:D1:A3:49:A7:F9:96:2A:82:12  -- >> But what is the sense of "X509v2 Subject Key Identifier"? And at the case I can set every value I want to this key, is that certificate chain unsecure?

Comment: The Subject/Authority key identifiers are just there to help build the certification path. [*Applications are not required to verify that key identifiers match when performing certification path validation.*](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5280#section-4.2.1.2). The fingerprints are also only used for organising the certificates (except for EV certs where they do a bit more). What you really need is matching issuer name to CA's subject name and checking that the signature is valid (using the issuer's public key).